# How do I use htaccess to block computers when %{REMOTE_HOST} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} are the same?

Tags: .htaccess

I have noticed that when %{REMOTE_HOST} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} are the same that the connecting computer is usually some form of bot.net or other hack attempt. The code I have is not working, but should give a feel for what I am looking for.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} =%{REMOTE_ADDR}
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot use** `%` variables on right hand side of `RewriteCond` directive.

This is tricky stuff but you can solve it with following rule using a back-reference:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}::%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.+?)::\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks for the incite on the % variables. However, the code you offered redirects everyone to the forbidden page.

Comment: I believe that the same results could be achieved if we check to see if %{REMOTE_HOST} returns an ip rather than returning a normal remote host name. Maybe use a regular expression to target any ip. This would block any future efforts for the suspicious computer when they work around the above (my original method) simply by making %{REMOTE_HOST} return an ip other than %{REMOTE_ADDR}. Where both would still return an ip, but both different. My original idea only checked if both were the same.

Comment: That is for you to decide but this rule is correct version of what you're trying to do in your rule and to meet this requirement: **when %{REMOTE_HOST} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} are the same that the connecting computer is usually some form of bot.net**

Comment: I tested your version and as I said, everyone was being redirected, not just those "when %{REMOTE_HOST} and %{REMOTE_ADDR} are the same." Moreover, I have seen the same code you offered on another stackoverflow page. I do not know if you are the original author or not, but I do know that this particular code is redirecting everyone.

Comment: As I said the flaw is in your logic **that you were trying to match** `%{REMOTE_HOST}` and `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`

Comment: When I said "this particular code," above, I was referring to the code you offered. I have acknowledged the flaw in my code and have thanked you for pointing it out. Your code however is flawed in that everyone is being redirected to the forbidden page and you seem to ignore this fact. While you have managed to point out my mistake, you have failed to offer any sound working script examples. I do thank you for your attempt.

Comment: I could offer a working solution if question had enough information like e.g. some samples of apache access logs when `%{REMOTE_HOST}` and `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`

Comment: Given the fact that you did not have enough information as you stated above in saying "I could offer a working solution if question had enough information," and asking for access logs, but first offering a salutation (your code), then claiming a lack of information, you are not qualified to offer a solution. From now on, offer no solutions until you know a.) that your solution is sound, and b.) that you have enough information to offer a sound solution.

Comment: 1. As I stated multiple times my solution is **direct translation of your (incorrect) rewrite rule**. 2. Since you later admit that you provided flawed logic, onus is on you to rectify it. 3. What are your credentials to question my qualification?